# i have a problem loading my 3d object (json file) in my 3d scene

Tags: json, three.js, loader

I have a problem loading my 3d object (json file) in my 3d scene.
have I not yet fully integrated my property?
I didn't assign any textures.

My model was created from blender using three.js exporter and is also displayed in the editor of threejs.org/editor. unfortunately with strange textures.

The browser loads the file 100% but tells me 2 errors. I'm not sure about that either.

I have provided the data here ...
ONEDRIVE
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuLWgHhoBqYGjFnq_69fwPtXcUKG?e=2TiBYS

ATTENTION please display as mobile version. I haven't designed a desktop view yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON file is not in the Object/Scene format. It's just geometry data. Instead of using `THREE.ObjectLoader`, try it with [THREE.BufferGeometryLoader](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=bufferge#api/en/loaders/BufferGeometryLoader).

Since the loader returns a geometry and no 3D object, you have to change your `onLoad()` callback a bit. Try it with:

```js
const loader = new THREE.BufferGeometryLoader();
loader.load( "3d/cappy-threejs.json", function ( geometry ) {

    scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial() ) );

} );
```

BTW: Please do not use the `three.js` Blender exporter anymore. It has been removed from the repository since a couple of years. Always export your assets to glTF and load them via `THREE.GLTFLoader`. More information about this topic in the following guide:

https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models

Comment: Hammer, ja es funktioniert!!! Ich danke dir vielmals. Jetzt kann ich endlich weiter arbeiten. Aber zuerst studiere ich ausführlich den Link den du empfohlen hast.  
Auch deiner Empfehlung den gltf-exporter zu verwenden und den -loader werde ich folgen.

Comment: Ich hatte so viele Ansätze, die ich noch probieren wollte um endlich mein Modell zu laden, aber Deine Korrektur mit dem THREE.BufferGeometryLoader hatte ich gar nicht auf dem schirm. da wäre ich ja niemals drauf gekommen. ich danke nochmal für deine schnelle Hilfe. 

Deine Antwort und dass ich nur die Geometrie geladen habe hilft mir sehr.

Ich wünsche dir alles gute und weiterhin viel Erfolg.

Comment: Please upvote/accept the answer if it solved your issue.